# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a store locator type of page. The user types in his/her zip code and then is taken to the results page.

On the results page, I first run geoencode to get the LatLng of the zip code and center the map to it. Then I go through the results div (which is populated from the database) and run geoencode for each of them and set markers for each. All the distance calculations are done on the database side, so I don't have to deal with them here. Then I set an info window and a click event so that when they open they get the appropriate info on their info window. This part all works fine.

The problem I'm having is dealing with when I get more than 10 results from the database. Google maps has a maximum of 10 api calls per second. So I tried creating a more results button, then when click, would display the next 10 results on the page and on the map.

```
$('#more-results').click(function(){
    var $elements = $('#dealer-results-dev li[data-index='+base+']').nextUntil( '#dealer-results-dev li[data-index='+(base + 11)+']' );
    $elements.slideDown();
    $elements.each(function(index, element){
        $element = $(element);
        var address = $element.find('span.address').html() + ' ' +$element.find('span.address2').html();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {  
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            markers.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                var $element = $('#dealer-results li:nth-child('+(index +1)+')')
                var contentString = '<div class="content">'+
                        '<h3>'+ $element.find('h3').html()+'</h3>'+
                        '<span>' + $element.find('span.distance').html() +'</span><br>'+
                        '<span>' + $element.find('span.address').html() +'</span><br>'+
                        '<span>' + $element.find('span.address2').html() +'</span><br>'+
                        '<span>' + $element.find('span.phone').html() + '</span><br>'+
                        '<span>Link</span>'+
                        '</div>';
                infowindow.setContent(contentString);
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            });
        }else{
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
});
base += 10;
```

});

I tried setting it to 5, but I was still getting the error at the 4th element.

Comment: So load them slower, insert a delay between requests and not in a loop.

Comment: You have to get the geo location for each location and store it server side. This is so you don't have to waste time and requests on locations you use multiple times.

Comment: @zeal, that's not a bad idea. I'm gonna talk to my backend developer about it.

Comment: I think we all dealt with this problem at some point. Try adding a catch(too fast Exception) and re-queuing the call to Google API.